# Sqoop Import Error "Could not load db driver class" with Amazon EMR Service

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, amazon-emr

> I have created a EMR cluster with hadoop,Sqoop and Spark
>   configuration. I am trying Sqoop Import but getting error "Could not
>   load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" . My question is which
>   location do we put the  Mysql Driver ?

```
I have tried putting the Jar at path 
1. /etc/sqoop/conf/ 
2. /etc/sqoop/lib/ (after creating the lib folder)
```

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://--.--.--.--:3306/xyz --table
>   sample_submission --target-dir /home/sqoop7 --username x --password y -m 1;

Answer (score 0):

Jars to put for sqoop is under `lib` dir in `SQOOP_HOME`

Full path: `/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/`